# How to run HTML from a User Input Box

Tags: html, input

I would like to know how to code a widget; when the user inputs HTML code into the input box and presses the run button, the result will pop up underneath the input box and run button. Also, when the text inside the input box is changed by document.getElementById.innerhtml, and the user clicks the run button, the code needs to run as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far.. if you are stuck somewhere we can help you.

Comment: What you want to build is called a *fiddle*, btw.